# Android Customizing Android Keyboard to provide enter or make keyboard dissappera

Tags: android, keyboard

During data entry I am not seeing a way to press enter and get the keyboard to disappear.  So when the user is entering say a phone number in an edit text keyboard appears but nothing seems to count an  so that it returns to the activity.  How can I customize the keyboard so that user can fill in a form and when they have finished entering the keyboard goes away. There might be someway to do this but I have not found it and it certainly is not intuitive for end user.  The keyboard needs to vanish between entries, and do so easily and intuitively.  I would like an intuitive way to handle this data entry problem.

Thanks,

Comment: looks like I might need to provide inputType for EditText

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested:

```
    <EditText android:imeOptions="actionDone" ...
```